# Не срабатывают операции с базой данных sqlite при событии click

Tags: phonegap, sqlite, javascript

Этот код рабочий:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (4)'); 
tx.executeSql(
    "SELECT * FROM Routes",
    [],
    function (tx, result) {
        alert(result.rows.item(0)['id_object']) },
    function (tx, error) {
        alert('Неудача');}
)};
```

Если этот же код вешаю на кнопку, то он перестает работать?

```
<button id = "click2">Добавить в БД</button>

 $('#click2').click(function(){
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (4)'); 
     tx.executeSql(
         "SELECT * FROM Routes", 
         [], 
         function (tx, result) { 
             alert(result.rows.item(0)['id_object']) },
         function (tx, error) {
             alert('Неудача');}
     )
 });
```

В чем ошибка? help.

Comment: может завернуть в `$(function() {})` ?

Comment: не понял. там же click стоит.

Comment: на кнопку лог по вешай, клик отрабатывает? может ты не по той кнопке кликаешь

Comment: тестил. алерт срабатывает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546220/no-database-is-running-on-event-click